# How to play .ts live tv link in exoPlayer

Tags: java, android, kotlin, video-streaming, exoplayer

I am trying to develop a TV app
I have a problem
I can't run the link of satellite channels in `ExoPlayer`

```
#EXTINF:
http://raoseditor.com:80/live/GLGhcHsrLV/LD5bWcpAaM/151092.ts
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for supported formats here https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/supported-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

The URL you have above, which appears to be for a ts media file, returns a '302' redirect response or a '403' forbidden response, depending on how you connect to it.

This is usually because the content requires some user login and/or some authorisation token to be included in the request.

If you do have authorisation for the content then the first step is to find out the format and make sure it is included in the ExoPlayer supported content list as Ramesh suggests in another answer. Note that the usual broadcast format support by satellite typically (unless it is IP over the satellite broadcast) need to be converted into an IP based format and streaming protocol to be played on an Android device.